# How do I debug a .NET executable at MSIL-level?

Tags: .net, debugging, cil

I have a .NET executable file that I need to debug.  I would like to step into it so that it stops on the first instruction and have a visual interface for single-stepping, breakpoints, etc.

This seems like it should be easier but I haven't yet found a solution!  I read about `DbgCLR.exe` on the web but I can't find that file on my system or online for the life of me.  I also read somewhere that `DbgCLR.exe` is no longer necessary because Visual Studio can do the same thing.  A Visual Studio .NET solution would be great, too!  (Maybe there's a menu item that I overlooked?)

Either will suit, so long as I can inspect the stack, set breakpoints, etc.

Comment: Good question. I used NTSD years ago for debugging JIT-ed MSIL code. That was a real joy... Check out http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/ and let me know if there is anything higher-level available now.

Comment: If you have symbols and sources, you can use VS to attach to the process and specify you want managed debugging in the attach dialog.

Answer (score 1):

If you're one to buy utilities - Red Gate's new .NET Reflector Pro does exactly that situation really well ($195).  I think you can get an evaluation version that last for a little while on [Red Gate's site](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm)

I've use [DILE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dile/) in the past to do that in IL, for some reason I've had mixed experiences with Deblector.

Probably not worth your time but you can also create pdb symbols for an exe but if the assembly has alot of references it gets complicated.  I put a blog post together a few years ago on how to do it: [Disassembling .NET - Appendix A](http://jasonhaley.com/blog/post/2007/04/05/DisassemblingNet-Appendix-A.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

WinDbg can be used as it automatically stops when the process initiated. However, it only displays native things unless you utilize SOS.dll and managed debugging skills. So it has a sharp learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

[Deblector](http://deblector.codeplex.com/Wikipage) allows you to single step  IL via reflector.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the executable to csharp (vb.net).
There is good and free tool, .Ned Reflector.